# sql Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total) causing error with mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, sql, session, mysql-num-rows

right i have confirmed the query `SELECT * FROM mbgeust WHERE user_name = '{$name}' AND user_pass = SHA1('{$pass}')` returns a result but it returns saying 'Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0005 sec)' sould that not be rows 0 - 1 as `mysql_num_rows($mysql)` is returning 0 despite the fact that the query returns one row here is my whole code

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include './inc/sql.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
            sql_start();
            $mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbgeust WHERE user_name = '{$name}' AND user_pass = SHA1('{$pass}')")
                or die ("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $mysql);
            if(mysql_num_rows($mysql) == 1){
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
                header('refresh:3; URL = /');
                die('You are now logged in!');
            }
            else{
                header('refresh:3; URL = /');
                die ('Password was probably incorrect!');
            }
            sql_stop();
            }
        echo "<form action='./' method='POST'>
        Username: <br/>
        <input type='text' name='username' /><br/>
        Password: <br/>
        <input type='password' name='password' /><br/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'/>
        </form>";
    }
    else {
        include 'main.php';
    }
?>
```

and sql.php

```
<?php
    function sql_start(){
        global $con;
        $con = mysql_connect("mackinnonsbakery.co.uk.mysql","mackinnonsbaker","UE9ux3cZ")
            or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("mackinnonsbaker", $con)
            or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    function sql_stop(){
        global $con;
        mysql_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Comment: its because Im using a global ($con) isn't it

Comment: i have also tried mysqli and I get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `mysql_real_escape_string` prior to `sql_start()`, so you have no active database connection - so  `$name` and `$pass` are probably set to `false`. Check your error logs you should see warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to mysqli and changed the sql_start/sql_stop in to separate included files at the start and end of the page this seams to have sorted it if anyone knows how to fix this without moving to mysqli provide an answer as it will help others here is my code at present:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include './inc/sql_start.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $pass = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM mbgeust WHERE user_name = '{$name}' AND user_pass = SHA1('{$pass}')";
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();
                if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
                    header('refresh:3; URL = /');
                    die('You are now logged in!');
                }
                else{
                    header('refresh:3; URL = /');
                    die ('Password was probably incorrect!');
                }
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }
        echo "<form action='./' method='POST'>
        Username: <br/>
        <input type='text' name='username' /><br/>
        Password: <br/>
        <input type='password' name='password' /><br/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'/>
        </form>";
    }
    else {
        include 'main.php';
    }
    include './inc/sql_stop.php';
?>
```

sql_start.php

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("mackinnonsbakery.co.uk.mysql", "mackinnonsbaker", "UE9ux3cZ", "mackinnonsbaker");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
?>
```

sql_stop.php

```
<?php
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

again if anyone has the real solution please post it